# Sharepoint Format Text tab in a compact view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

So today while editing a page in sharepoint i suddenly noticed all the tabs for the page edit is in some form of a compact view. I do not recall changing it, perhaps i hit some kind if keybind. How would i be able to change the view back so all of the options are not in a drop down menu style.

[image: sharepoint edit dropdown menu view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the formatting on the ribbon is based off of your windowed view. There physically is not enough space for all the elements to fit in the ribbon. To expand the ribbon, expand your window.

The first image below is my full-screen view of the page and has all the bells a whistles in their expanded view. The second image is a partial window. Try either zooming out (maybe your browser is at 150% zoom), or changing monitors, or maximizing your window.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would be the problem! I wouldn't have thought the page would enter a different view if it were zoomed out.

I was on 90% zoom to view an entire page without having to use a bottom scroll bar.

Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: No problem. Best of luck.